# Setting Scrapy start_urls from a Script

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython, web-scraping, scrapy

I have a working scrapy spider and I'm able to run it through a separate script following the [example here](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#run-from-script). I have also created a wxPython GUI for my script that simply contains a multi-line TextCtrl for users to input a list of URLs to scrape and a button to submit. Currently the start_urls are hardcoded into my spider - How can I pass the URLs entered in my TextCtrl to the start_urls array in my spider? Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just set `start_urls` on your `Spider` instance:

```
spider = FollowAllSpider(domain=domain)
spider.start_urls = ['http://google.com']
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked - however, only with one URL. It doesn't seem to parse multiple URLs on multiple lines into the correct format for start_urls. I get the results when entering a single URL, but not multiple. Any advice on how to do that? This is my current approach: `spider.start_urls = [self.tc2.GetValue()]`

Comment: How do you set multiple urls? What is `self.tc2`?

Comment: Sorry, `self.tc2` is my multiline TextCtrl. For example, when I use `savefile = open('urls.txt', 'w')` `savefile.write(self.tc2.GetValue())` it creates a text file with mutiple lines, just as it was input into the TextCtrl. I think what I need to know is how to parse the multiple lines into an array format where each line is separated by a comma. Does that make sense?

Comment: @user994585 try `spider.start_urls = self.tc2.GetValue().splitlines()`.

Comment: It is not clear to me how the code in this answer can be integrated with the example the question is based on. The example - from the official documentation - passes a spider class into `process.crawl(). This answer, however, is based on using a spider instance...?

Answer (score 9):

[alecxe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23479961/2107985) answer doesn't work for me. My solution works for Scrapy==1.0.3 :

```
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from tutorial.spiders.some_spider import SomeSpider

process = CrawlerProcess()

process.crawl(SomeSpider, start_urls=["http://www.example.com"])
process.start()
```

It might help someone in the future.