# scrapy crawl works well in command, but have something worry when running from a script

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm having some problems with scrapy. when i run command `scrapy crawl album -o test.xml`, the spider works well. but when i crawl from a script, i give a **different** `start_urls` to the spider, but get the **same** reusult with *command*. Both url are available. Here is the code I have written. Please point out what I am doing wrong, thanks.

**Spider file** `xiami_scrapy.py`

```
import scrapy
empty_referer = {
    'Referer': ''
}

class AlbumSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'album'
    start_urls = [
        'http://www.xiami.com/artist/album-eJlX61793',
    ]
    artist = 'giga'

    def __init__(self, url=None, artist=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AlbumSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if artist is not None:
            self.artist = artist
        if url is not None:
            self.start_urls = [url]

    def parse(self, response):
        for album in response.css('.album_item100_thread'):
            yield {
                'artist': self.artist,
                'title': album.css('.name>a>strong::text').extract_first(),
                'fav_count': album.css('.fav_c_ico::text').extract_first(),
                'star_rating': album.css('.album_rank>em::text').extract_first(),
                'release_date': response.css('.company>a::text')[1].extract().strip(),
                'company': album.css('.company>a::text')[0].extract(),
                'url': album.css('.name>a::attr(href)').extract_first(),
            }

        next_page = response.css('.p_redirect_l::attr(href)').extract_first()
        if next_page is not None:
            next_page = response.urljoin(next_page)
            yield scrapy.Request(next_page, headers=empty_referer, callback=self.parse)
```

**Script file** `test.py`

```
from twisted.internet import reactor, defer
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerRunner
from xiamiscrapy.spiders.xiami_scrapy import AlbumSpider
from scrapy.utils.log import configure_logging

configure_logging({'LOG_FORMAT': '%(levelname)s: %(message)s'})
runner = CrawlerRunner()

@defer.inlineCallbacks
def crawl():
    spider = AlbumSpider(url='http://www.xiami.com/artist/album-bzMAng64c0a',artist='reol')
    yield runner.crawl(spider)
    reactor.stop()

crawl()
reactor.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are setting the value of `start_urls` in spider constructor, you refer it as `self.start_urls`. That way, however, you set instance attribute of your spider class, while `start_urls` is a class attribute. That's why it doesn't work.

Take a look at this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23479895/setting-scrapy-start-urls-from-a-script) for ways how to do it correctly.